# Electric and Magnetic Weyl Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, relativity

The Weyl tensor can be decomposed in its electric and magnetic parts. In spherical symmetry the magnetic part vanishes, but in cylindrical symmetry it does not.

Why the magnetic part of Weyl tensor vanishes in spherical symmetry?